UR5 velocity control through waypoint trajectory
I want to try to spray paint with my robot, but in order to get a even coating i need to be able to set both the waypoint and the velocity that the tcp is supposed to have through the waypoint. In the first run i want to try to just do a 2D pattern with a zig zag pattern and get a even coating on it. Is this possible with the UR5 using MoveIt or other interfaces?
